# Generate bytecode from Eclipse's CompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode, eclipse-jdt, compilationunit

I am **not** working on an Eclipse plug-in project; however, I use an external library that generates an instance of org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit. Is there a way to generate Java bytecode from it?

Some searching revealed that CompilationUnit's are typically built by registering a custom builder for the Eclipse project, then letting eclipse invoke it... but I couldn't find any way to leverage that for a stand-alone application.

Comment: Maybe you should clearify your question ... what exactly do you want to know? Is it related to byte code generation? To leverage JDT from standaone application? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Partial Program Analysis for Java](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/ppa/) tool can, theoretically, do this, by using the `PPAUtil` class:

```
PPAUtil.compileCU(myCompilationUnit, baseOutputFolder)
```

Though in practice it only expects `CompilationUnit` instances it creates by itself with `PPAUtil.getCU(file, options, reqName, false)`, so I don't know if it will work on a `CompilationUnit` instance not produced this way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have a look at the code in [Apache Commons JCI](http://commons.apache.org/jci/). It implements an [eclipse compiler](https://github.com/apache/commons-jci/blob/1.1/compilers/eclipse/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/jci/compilers/EclipseJavaCompiler.java) for standalone applications.

Comment: I looked and it can convert an ICompilationUnit (which is surprisingly not related to CompilationUnit). However, it does seem like a good tool which takes me in the right direction, so thanks!